# Javaswing : load data from sql to java swing

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jbutton

when i click button , it show one value . Then i click again and it's still the same ,how to click button and it show a new value next ?

```
try {
 String bdUrl = jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=login;user=sa;password=123;"
 Connection conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(bdUrl);
 String sql = "select cauhoi , caul,cau2,cau3,caudung from tracnghiem";
 Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
 Resultset rs = statement.excuteQuery(sql);

 while (rs.next())
    {
      String cauhoil = rs.getString(1);
      String dapana = rs.getString(2);
      String dapanb = rs.getString(3);
      String dapanc = rs.getString(4);
      String dapand = rs.getString(5);

      lbl.setText(""+cauhoil);
      jrd1.setText(dapana);
      jrd2.setText(dapanb);
      jrd3.setText(dapanc);
      jrd4.setText(dapand);

    }}
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and post it here. Please don't post your entire code but rather create a small runnable class, that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: 1) In addition to the sage advice of @SergiyMedvynskyy. *Never* post images of text (or links to them), post the text itself! 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the same value because your SQL statement is the same every time it is executed. You will always see the last value in the ResultSet since you keep updating the Swing components inside the loop.

Instead you need to:

1. create a custom object to store each of the 5 values for each row of data in the database
2. Then you need to read the data once and inside your while loop you need to create an instance of this object with each of the 5 values.
3. This object will then be added to an ArrayList
4. When you click a button you get an object from the ArrayList and display the values in your Swing components.
5. You then increment an index variable so that then next time you click a button you get the next object from the ArrayList.